# Replace the text within 0 or more html tags

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a table with a column that contains varchar2 strings like the following.

```
My dog chases my cat
<p>My dog ate my other cat</p>
<p><div id="abcd">My cat ate my hamster</div><p>
<p><b><div id="abcd">My hamster sleeps all the time</div></b></p>
```

I need to do a SUBSTR on the text within the html tags.

I'm thinking that numbered groups is the way to go but I can't get the the closing tag into its own group. This is the sql I have:

```
WITH sentences AS 
(
SELECT 1 as nr, 'My dog chases my cat' AS ln FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2, '<p>My dog ate my other cat</p>' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 3,'<p><x><div id="abcd">My cat ate my hamster</div></x></p>' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 4,'<p><b><div id="abcd">My hamster sleeps all the time</div></b></p>' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT nr, regexp_replace(ln, '^((<[^>]+>)+)(.*)((<[^>]+>)+)$', 'group 1:\1,group 2:\2,group 3:\3,group 4:\4', 1, 1, 'n')
FROM sentences order by nr;

RETURNS

1   My dog chases my cat
2   group 1:<p>,group 2:<p>,group 3:My dog ate my other cat,group 4:</p>
3   group 1:<p><x><div id="abcd">,group 2:<div id="abcd">,group 3:My cat ate my hamster</div></x>,group 4:</p>
4   group 1:<p><b><div id="abcd">,group 2:<div id="abcd">,group 3:My hamster sleeps all the time</div></b>,group 4:</p>
```

Group 4 only contains one closing tag, the other closing tag(s) is/are in group 3 as shown in row 3 and 4. What pattern do I need to get all closing tags in their own numbered group ?

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/266304) You might be able to get something to work with those specific strings, but in general,not a good idea.

Comment: There are too many edge cases for you to reliably work with HTML using regexes.  Here are some examples: http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having said not to do this, you're actually only one character out, for these specific values anyway:

```
WITH sentences AS 
(
SELECT 1 as nr, 'My dog chases my cat' AS ln FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2, '<p>My dog ate my other cat</p>' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 3,'<p><x><div id="abcd">My cat ate my hamster</div></x></p>' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 4,'<p><b><div id="abcd">My hamster sleeps all the time</div></b></p>' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT nr,
  regexp_replace(ln, '^((<[^>]+>)+)(.*?)((<[^>]+>)+)$', 'group 1:\1,group 2:\2,group 3:\3,group 4:\4', 1, 1, 'n') as str
--------------------------------------^
FROM sentences order by nr;
```

Without that `?` making the `.*` non-greedy, you're including the earlier end tags in that third group, and only the final end-tag goes in group 4 because it has to.

```
NR STR                                                                                                                     
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 My dog chases my cat                                                                                                    
 2 group 1:<p>,group 2:<p>,group 3:My dog ate my other cat,group 4:</p>                                                    
 3 group 1:<p><x><div id="abcd">,group 2:<div id="abcd">,group 3:My cat ate my hamster,group 4:</div></x></p>              
 4 group 1:<p><b><div id="abcd">,group 2:<div id="abcd">,group 3:My hamster sleeps all the time,group 4:</div></b></p>
```

Or just that group:

```
SELECT nr, regexp_replace(ln, '^((<[^>]+>)+)(.*?)((<[^>]+>)+)$', '\3', 1, 1, 'n') as str
FROM sentences order by nr;

NR STR                           
-- ------------------------------
 1 My dog chases my cat          
 2 My dog ate my other cat       
 3 My cat ate my hamster         
 4 My hamster sleeps all the time
```